# Remove last line from file excerpt

Tags: python, string, line

I'm trying to copy an excerpt from a txt file into a variable and then printing it. It looks for tomorrow's date, and then it prints everything between that and the current date. However, today's day is being printed, as it is located before today's date.

E.g:

Friday 24/5

[content im looking for]

Thursday 23/5

When I try to print this, it includes Thursday as well, which is not a part of what I want to print.

Do you guys have an easy way to remove the Thursday?

```
file=open("plan.txt","r")
s = file.read()
dayresult = ((s.split(str(tomorrowerino)))[1].split(str(todayerino))[0]).strip()
dayresult[dayresult.find('\n')+1:dayresult.rfind('\n')]
print dayresult
```

Here is what it outputs:

> "
>
> Geografi
>
> Vi har geografi istedenfor samfunnsfag.    Norsk
>
> Les side 75 til 82, og gjør oppsummeringsoppgavene 1 til 10 side 83.
>
> Torsdag
>
> "

The second to last line is what I tried to use to remove the Torsdag, but it didn't do anything.

(Torsdag means Thursday, and that is what I want removed)

Also, the days will vary, so I can't just subtract that from the string.

(I have the code for the variables if you need them to help, but I don't see how they're relevant atm.)

Thank you :)

Comment: you need to reassign the value to `dayresult` in this line `dayresult = dayresult[dayresult.find('\n')+1:dayresult.rfind('\n')]`, otherwise your dayresult won't change

Comment: @iulian Thanks, but now it seems to remove the first word as well, any tips for a fix?

Comment: remove the `+1` in your `dayresult.find('\n')+1`

Comment: Now it prints a line, but the word on that line is missing for some reason...

Comment: try this `dayresult = dayresult[:dayresult.rfind('\n')]`

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks so much for the help :D

Comment: I left an answer as well, for those with similar situations. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave it as an answer as well, for any who will encounter similar situations:

Whenever you use list slicing, it doesn't change the list (or any other sequence type variables like `str`, `tuple`, `unicode`) it is called on, but creates a new one. You need to reassign the value of the sliced list to itself:

```
dayresult = dayresult[:dayresult.rfind('\n')]
```

Also, the slicing happens from the first character, until the last row.